# CMake build directory (chosen in gui) variable

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

While running the cmake's script, I would like to obtain the path to the main build folder, which one chooses, for example in CMake Gui via "Where to build the binaries" text input.

Best match that I have found so far is the PROJECT_BINARY_DIR variable, that unfortunately gets you the folder:  ./build/modules/project_name.

I would like to get the .../build folder only.

I know I can extract .../build from .../build/modules/project_name with some hacking but would anyway like to get the .../build directly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CMAKE_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html) is what you are looking for. It is an absolute path to the top level folder of your build directory.